# Uploading large files to web service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, file-upload, oracle10g

Good morning everyone:

I've been searching the internet and have not found what to do on this.

I'm currently trying to upload a file bigger than 100 MB to the **UCM** (Universal Content Management of Oracle 10g) web service. It works fine on files smaller than **100 MB** but with bigger files I get the ***10055 socket error*** saying that there is not avaiable buffer space or queue is full.

So I have no way to chage the UCM Web service but I would like to know if I change my code somehow to upload this big files.
The WS offers a method that receives the byte array (**byte[]**) containing the file contents, no chunks...

Any help, hints, tips or tricks will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: If you are in control of this file that is being uploaded, then can you not upload it in batches?

Comment: Well, researching a bit more I've found that the problem seems to be at the client, because the web service is never called when the file is bigger than 100 MB.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what webserver you're running it might just need configuring to allow large requests. For IIS try [here](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/security/requestFiltering/requestLimits).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Matthew. Yes, I'm using IIS, but it's a 5.1 IIS, this article is about 6.0 and upper versions.

Comment: Does this question help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792386/uploading-in-asp-to-iis-5-1